# pass variable data from current php page to ajax and then to other php

Tags: php, ajax

Please look at data: `{limit: lim , offset: off, personname: $personname, fname: $fname},`

Is it the right way to pass data from current `php` to `ajax`?

```
<?php
$personname='Prakash';
$fname='';
$surname='';
?>
<script> 
function displayRecords(lim, off) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "getrecords.php",
        data: {personname: $personname, fname: $fname},
        success: function(html) {
            $("#results").append(html);
                                }
          });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I don't think that will matter. I have passed personname: $personname. I think this is the wrong way. I don't know the correct way.

Comment: $personname='Prakash';
$fname='';
$surname=''; these are php variable or jquery variable ?

Comment: Those are php variables.

Comment: you need to pass the php variable like this data: {personname: '<?php echo $personname; ?>', fname: '<?php echo $fname; ?>'}, take look on my below answer @PrakashPatil

Comment: Thanks @JYoThI and everyone for helping me out. Without your support I would never have got the answer to it. "Thanks a ton" that's what came from my heart when it worked for me. I tick JYoThl's answer as it was easiest to understand and I was focused at.

Comment: Green tick is deserved  @Pritamkumar answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `PHP variable` should be `passed` in `jquery`  like below

```
data: {personname: '<?php echo $personname; ?>', fname: '<?php echo $fname; ?>'},
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have to write like this:

`php variable` in `JavaScript` should be written  as `'<?php echo $val;?>'`

```
 <?php 
    $personname='Prakash';
    $fname='';
    $surname='';
   ?>
    function displayRecords(lim, off) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: "getrecords.php",
            data: {limit: lim , offset: off, personname: '<?php echo $personname;?>, fname: '<?php echo $fname?>'},
            beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
            },
            success: function(html) {
            $("#results").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            }
            });
            }
```

Comment: +1 from me. You were the first to answer this and the other answers are basicly just copies of it. I think good sportmanship should be in order here.

Comment: when i post comment while i didn't notice your answer . + from me . @prakash patil green tick is deserved this answer

Comment: i know my answer is correct but your answer is posted before mine . so it's should be appreciated with green tick . @Prakash Patil

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $personname='Prakash';
    $fname='';
    $surname='';
?>
<script>
    function displayRecords(lim, off) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    url: "getrecords.php",
                    data: {limit: lim , offset: off, personname: <?php echo $personname;?>, fname:<?php echo $fname;?>},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
                        $('#loader_image').show();
                    },
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#results").append(html);
                        $('#loader_image').hide();
                    }
                    });
            }

</script>
```